# tkinterでbindした関数についてエラーがでます: TypeError: chek_high() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, anaconda

pythonが使えるanaconda を使い、High and low ゲームを作成しています。

tkinterで以下の通りに書いて実行したらエラーが表示されました。
どうすればよいでしょうか。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: chek_high() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

**現状のコード:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import random as ran
mark = ['spade','diamond','heart','club']
num  = range(1,14)
cards= [(i,j)for i in mark for j in num]
ran.shuffle(cards)
print(cards)
open_card   = cards[1][1]
answer_card = cards[2][1]

root = tk.Tk()


#======================GUI=======================#

root.title(u"High and low game")
root.geometry("1000x750")
lb = tk.Label(root,text=u"High and low game スタート!!",font = ('Arial',25))
lb.grid(row=0)
lb2 = tk.Label(root,text=u"現在のカードは、",font = ('Arial',20))
lb2.grid(row=1)
lb3 = tk.Label(root,text=open_card,font = ('Arial',300))
lb3.grid(row=2)
lb4 = tk.Label(root,text=u"Highかな❓❔ lowかな❓❔",font = ('Arial',20))
lb4.grid(row=3)
def chek_high():
    if open_card < answer_card:
        lb5 = tk.Label(root,text=u"お見事‼　正解‼",font = ('Arial',20))
        lb5.pack()
    elif open_card > answer_card:
        lb6 = tk.Label(root,text=u"残念　不正解…",font = ('Arial',25))
        lb6.pack()
    root.mainloop()
high = tk.Button(root,text=u'High',width=10)
high.bind("<Button-1>",chek_high)
high.grid(column=0, row=4)
low = tk.Button(root,text=u'low',width=10)
low.grid(column=2, row=4)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: この通りです]

Comment: こちらの記事が参考になりそうです。[Python tkinter イベントハンドラをbindメソッドで追加する](https://randkurt.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-345.html) の`イベントに関連付ける関数`の説明を参照。

Answer (score 1):

下記でひとまずエラーなく動作するようになるかと思います。

修正点は下記2点です。

1. `def chek_high():` →　`def chek_high(event):`
   [コールバック関数](https://office54.net/python/tkinter/tkinter-bind-event#section3)
2. chek_high関数内のpack()をgrid()に変更（併用できないのでgridに統一）

ただし下記コードでは数字ぴったりの場合に何も表示されないのでその場合の対応を考える必要があるかと思います。

**修正後のコード:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import random as ran
mark = ['spade','diamond','heart','club']
num  = range(1,14)
cards= [(i,j)for i in mark for j in num]
ran.shuffle(cards)
print(cards)
open_card   = cards[1][1]
answer_card = cards[2][1]

root = tk.Tk()


#======================GUI=======================#

root.title(u"High and low game")
root.geometry("1000x750")
lb = tk.Label(root,text=u"High and low game スタート!!",font = ('Arial',25))
lb.grid(row=0)
lb2 = tk.Label(root,text=u"現在のカードは、",font = ('Arial',20))
lb2.grid(row=1)
lb3 = tk.Label(root,text=open_card,font = ('Arial',300))
lb3.grid(row=2)
lb4 = tk.Label(root,text=u"Highかな❓❔ lowかな❓❔",font = ('Arial',20))
lb4.grid(row=3)
def chek_high(event):
    if open_card < answer_card:
        lb5 = tk.Label(root,text=u"お見事‼　正解‼",font = ('Arial',20))
        # lb5.pack()
        lb5.grid(column=0, row=5)
    elif open_card > answer_card:
        lb6 = tk.Label(root,text=u"残念　不正解…",font = ('Arial',25))
        # lb6.pack()
        lb6.grid(column=0, row=5)
    root.mainloop()
high = tk.Button(root,text=u'High',width=10)
high.bind("<Button-1>",chek_high)
high.grid(column=0, row=4)
low = tk.Button(root,text=u'low',width=10)
low.grid(column=2, row=4)

lb5 = tk.Label(root)
lb5.grid(column=0, row=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: 分かりやすい説明でバグを修正することが出来ました。大変助かりました。